# Incrementally concatenate string inside Angular template (i.e. in the view)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, string-concatenation

Inside an `ng-repeat`, I am trying to add a bit of text to a variable.

The real reason I am doing this, is because I have a recursive template and I want to keep adding to the same variable. But I've created a simple example here to demonstrate just part of the the problem I'm having in the hopes it can help me solve the other issues.

I am expecting the screen to print all of the numbers, followed by one 'b' each, like

```
1b
2b
3b
...
```

Instead, it prints out

```
1bbbbbbbbbbb
2bbbbbbbbbbb
3bbbbbbbbbbb
...
```

Why?

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fd1f6yso/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why?

Because that's how data-binding works by default: each time value of `num` variable changes, the expression is recalculated - changing the `num` again, and again, and again. Eventually it stops; have you checked the console, you'd have seen plenty of '10 $digest iterations reached' errors. And that's why you see exactly 10 `b` printed in each row.

It's easy enough to get rid of the problem if you want the same number of `b` printed at each step:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <div ng-repeat="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] track by $index">
      <label>{{num + 'b'}}</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want to build some sort of pyramid, incrementing the `b`-count, that's a bit trickier. Here's one possible approach:

```
App.controller("ctrl",function ($scope){
    $scope.myNum = 0;
    $scope.decorateWithB = function(num) {
        return num + Array(+num + 1).join('b');
    };
});

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="acc='b'">
     <div ng-repeat="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] track by $index">
         <label>{{decorateWithB(num)}}</label>
     </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fd1f6yso/1/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't ask it in the best way possible for what I am confused about. I reasked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590337/update-an-angular-variable-in-the-view

Comment: You've asked it quite ok, but you didn't really check my answer. ) Here's the [solution for your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/qsc2ka8o/) - as you see, there's the same approach: move the recursive inside the controller.

Comment: The way I'm doing recursive is by calling a template using `ng-include` and calling it from within itself

Answer (score 4):

with `{num = (num+'b')`

you are updating num reference of previous iterations as well adding 'b' to each refrence each time and it get updates like

> 1 + "b" => 1b + "b" => 1bb + "b" so on
>
> 2 + "b" => 2b + "b" => 2bb + "b" so on

so dont assign just add "b" , like

```
(num+'b')
```

**Demo**

```js
var App = angular.module("App",[]);

App.controller("ctrl",function ($scope){
    $scope.myNum = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
         <div ng-repeat="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">
             <label>{{ (num+'b')}}</label>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't ask it in the best way possible for what I am confused about. I reasked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590337/update-an-angular-variable-in-the-view

Comment: yes you did a fine job making separate question as it was not obvoius here let me see there :) @Imray