# Update an Angular variable in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like my output to read

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
etc...
```

I expected this simple code I wrote to do the trick, but instead it prints

```
01111111111 011111111111
02222222222 022222222222
03333333333 033333333333
04444444444 044444444444
05555555555 055555555555
06666666666 066666666666
```

Why is this happening?

This is my Angular code:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div ng-repeat="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">
         <label>{{previousNumber}}</label>
         {{previousNumber = (previousNumber + "" + num)}}
     </div>
</div>
```

And here's the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fd1f6yso/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you both `$watch` - with `{{previousNumber}}` -  and modify `previousNumber` with every evaluation of the expression `{{previousNumber = (previousNumber + "" + num)}}`, you get into an infinite loop - which Angular prevents after 10 iterations of `$digest`.

To achieve what you want, you'd need a variable in the outer scope of your `ng-repeat` to keep the increasing string, and a local variable in the child (inner) scope of each `ng-repeat` iteration created with `ng-init`:

```
<div ng-init="label = ''">
    <div ng-repeat="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] track by $index" 
         ng-init="$parent.label = $parent.label+''+num; thisLabel = $parent.label">
        <label>{{thisLabel}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to use `$parent.label` (instead of `label`) due to how prototypical inheritance of literals works.

It should be noted that while this is fine for an intellectual exercise, I would NOT recommend this in real development.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we4f49n2/1/)

Comment: Why would you not recommend this in real developement? And what would you recommend instead?

Comment: Typically, it's better to perform this logic not in the View, but in the Service/Controller, or if it's View-specific - in a controller. It's reusable, more readable, easier to test. The logic in the View should be limited and constrained to View-only logic.

Comment: But in this case, the recursivity is provided in the view. It doesn't work in the controller

Comment: The View is driven by the ViewModel. The normal approach would be to construct the ViewModel to have the recursively created strings, and have the View just render it. But, in any case, you know your design better than anyone here.

Comment: @Imray, did the answer address your question otherwise?

Comment: the part of `ng-init` really helped. I'm using it now and it's working